# How to determine MS Access field size via OleDb

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb, jet

The existing application is in C#. During startup the application calls a virtual method to make changes to the database (for example a new revision may need to calculate a new field or something). An open OleDb connection is passed into the method.

I need to change a field width. The ALTER TABLE statement is working fine. But I would like to avoid executing the ALTER TABLE statement if the field is already the appropriate size. Is there a way to determine the size of an MS Access field using the same OleDb connection?

Comment: You mean JET and not ACCESS, as you're using only the database engine and not the database application programming tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question completely.
But you could query the table for 0 rows (SELECT 1 FROM myTable WHERE 1= 0)

And you could use recordet's field collection, refer to that field by name or index
and use field's property like size, type etc.

Does that help?

Comment: Here is what I came up with:

var command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT FIELD FROM TABLE", connection);
var reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly);
var schema = reader.GetSchemaTable();
var size = Convert.ToInt32(table.Rows[0]["ColumnSize"]);

Comment: But how would you know if it's a fixed width NCHAR, variable width NVARCHAR or blob MEMO? Does it have the WITH COMPRESSION option? Better to go with the OpenSchema method (+ ADOX if necessary) IMO: you get more/granular information.

Comment: The schema table had the dbtype, but I did not need it. I know the field type in this case...I just need the current field size and prefer to use the existing OleDb connection. OpenSchema may be a better solution for a different problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I came up with based on shahkalpesh's answer:

```
var command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT FIELD FROM TABLE", connection); 
var reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly); 
var schema = reader.GetSchemaTable(); 
var size = Convert.ToInt32(table.Rows[0]["ColumnSize"]);
```

Comment: Remou's answer is actually superior as it doesn't require opening a recordset, and you're using the tools provided in ADO for querying the data dictionary.

Comment: Are you sure? Remou's answer is walking a recordset (While Not rs.EOF ... rs.MoveNext). Note that I only needed size and preferred to use existing connection. Remou's answer may be a better answer to a different problem.